# Открыть apache доступ в домашнюю директорию пользователя

Tags: linux, apache, debian

Пытаюсь переместить файлы с /var/www в ~/www. Добавил пользователя www-data в группу моего пользователя и наоборот. Но апач выдает ошибку

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Ставил права на папку 777, результат тот же. Сейчас стоит debian8, до этого такая же проблема была на ubuntu. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

В конфигурационном файле апача, у меня /etc/apache2/apache2.conf дописать:

```
<Directory /home/username/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы на свою домашнюю папку права дали, или только на ~/www? `sudo chmod 755 ~`